# get the content in List returned by Service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight Application with a service reference.

In the service refernce i have a sql connection in which it will query the sql and return a data.

Code:

```
USE Chamber4 

Select count(*) as Zero From Table2 where Status = 0

Select count(*) as One From Table2 where Status = 1

Select count(*) as Two From Table2 where Status = 2
```

I want to send these data to an Silverlight application and display it in textbox

What format should I send the data ?
How do I retrieve the data in the silverlight application ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're doing here. What do you mean "an sql connection in the service reference"?

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight talks to databases via a WCF service or RIA Services.  I use RIA services with LINQ-Entities.

Simply add an EDMX model to your project.  Add your database connection, then add a domain service to your project and it will create the queries you can call from your Silverlight app.

http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/